# Adaptive card user add image to card

Tags: c#, botframework, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

Is there a way for a user to paste an image into an adaptive card component?

Background information : I'm creating an extension message in teams for our escalation channel, where users enter information about an issue they are having and sometimes a user posts an image alongside the problem, therefore the adaptive card will need to have the same functionality.

[Messaging Extension Card User Sees](https://i.stack.imgur.com/USa2z.jpg)

From looking around it seems you have to upload an image somewhere and then provide the URL to show an image.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Why not have the user just send the attachment in Teams with an attachment prompt outside of the card?

Comment: Adaptive Card Image only accepts a imageUrl. You cannot directly paste an image inside the Adaptive card.

Comment: @KyleDelaney Would it be possible to get the prompt to work whilst in the Extension message state?(I.e. after they filled in the card, the next thing to happen was a prompt, after user selects image to upload, card is posted with image uploaded below). To explain, since this bot will go in our escalation channel, I only want the bot outputting 1 message to the channel, with the form card and any images below the card. (I've had a look at the TeamsFileUpload example, but this wouldn't work as it's 3 steps so everyone in our company would get messaged each time).

Comment: @AlexCurtis - I think I see the problem. You want the bot to only send one message to the channel and then have the fields of an Adaptive Card to be sent to the bot in the same message as an image attachment to minimize the amount of messages that get displayed. Is that correct? If so, you've already mentioned the image URL solution and it seems you don't like it, so is Hilton's task module idea acceptable? I believe task modules can include multiple steps that only one user sees. Another solution would be to have the user click submit and upload an image in response to the same bot message.

Answer (score 0):

Of course I could be wrong, but I'm not aware of a way to do this inside an Adaptive Card. Another possible suggestion though is, instead of your Message Extension sending an Adaptive Card, have it open a url instead (see the [Task Modules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/what-are-task-modules#task-module-deep-link-syntax) docs and you'll see that you can either send back a Card, or a URL to a web page you host somewhere). If you instead point at your own custom web page, which will load in the same frame as the card currently loads into, you can do whatever you want - it's a custom web app, just framed into Teams. The page I linked to even shows an example of a PowerApp embedded in there.

Answer (score 0):

Convert your Image to a base64 url of the image, then set the images url to be that base64.

```
public static string ToBase64(this Image image)
{
    using (MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream())
    {
        image.Save(m, ImageFormat.Png);
        byte[] imageBytes = m.ToArray();

        string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
        return $"data:image/png;base64,{base64String}";
    }

}
```

```
AdaptiveCardTemplate template = new AdaptiveCardTemplate(templateJson);

string cardJson = template.Expand(new {imgUrl: image.ToBase64()});

using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("POST"), _teamsWebhook))
    {
        request.Content = new StringContent(cardJson);
        request.Content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json");

        var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);

        if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            throw new Exception(response.StatusCode.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

templateJson:

```
{
  "type": "message",
  "attachments": [
    {
      "contentType": "application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive",
      "contentUrl": null,
      "content": {
        "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
        "type": "AdaptiveCard",
        "version": "1.5",
        "body": [
          {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "size": "Medium",
            "weight": "Bolder",
            "text": "${subject}"
          },
          {
            "type": "Image",
            "url": "${imgUrl}",
            "size": "Stretch"
          }
        ]

      }
    }
  ]
}
```